# Trouble creating a simple array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a bit of trouble creating a simple array in Java where a random number is generated every time it loops. My code is as follows:

```
public class Q1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner listScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Size of list to sort?");
        int j = listScan.nextInt();


    int listArray[] = new int[j];

    for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++){
        listArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 +1);
    }

    System.out.println(listArray);


}
```

}

but the code gives me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Lab3.Q1.main(Q1.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: Change your for loop to this" `for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)` you have an array of j elements, indexes go from 0 to j - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this part of your code:

```
int listArray[] = new int[j];

for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++){
    listArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 +1);
}
```

It should be changed to this:

```
int listArray[] = new int[j];

for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
    listArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 +1);
}
```

Notice how `<=` was changed to `<`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++){
```

vs:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
```

For pretty much all coding, including `java`, **counting starts at `0`**. So where you would normally say `5`, in coding you would say `4`.

Let's say the length of the array is `3`, meaning it contains `0, 1, and 2`. So, when doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++){
```

`j` = the length of the array, so 3.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
```

now, it will loop threw the numbers `0, 1, 2, and 3`. Yet, our array does not contain a 3, it contains only `0, 1, and 2`. So, if we were to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++){
```

`j` = 3

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
```

Using this new code, it will loop threw `0, 1, and 2`, the same size of our array, `0, 1, and 2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int listArray[] = new int[j];  // Assume j =5. creates array of 5 elements.

    for (int i = 0; i <= j; i++){  // iterates from index 0 to 5 i.e, 6 elements . change it to i<j. it will work. 
        listArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100 +1);
    }
```

Note : You get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to access an index which is greater than the array's length.

Answer (score 1):

You're 1 index too high. Use

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You're for-loop is going 1 index position too far. You can't include the actual `j` value as an index position. The last index position is 1 less than the length. So do this:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
   ```
2. You're not printing your array properly. You can't print an array like this: `System.out.println(array);` so you have two options:

   ```
   System.out.println( Arrays.toString(listArray) );

   // or iterate through the array

   for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(listArray[i]);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the array, in Java is an static structure, and it won´t change it size directly, as you add elements. You can use another types of objects, more suitable as ArrayList.

Comment: No. He can use Array here. He knows the size (j). He is doing i<=j thats why he is getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException